# upload-images-in-Razor-Pages ASP.NET Core Web App .Net7

Tags: image, asp.net-core, upload, razor-pages, .net-7.0

I have an application that is a CRUD operation. However, when I try to upload a single or multiple images, they do not upload properly and there seems to be an issue. I have searched a lot but haven't found a solution to the problem.

Can someone help me and explain the best way to make this feature work correctly?"

```
namespace ArtsRP.Model
{
    public class Orders
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DesignGoal { get; set; }
        public string ContentText { get; set; }
        public string TargetPlatform { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public List<string> SimilarDesignsImages { get; set; }
        public string FinalDesignImage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to modify the model . Besides, where do you want to upload-images ?A cotroller method ?  Could you share some error message ?

Comment: "there seems to be an issue". Please provide details of the issue. What have you actually tried?